# adding to the windows explorer recognized locations

Tags: c++, windows-explorer

In Windows Explorer, if I type in certain strings in the address bar, it will recognize them and auto-complete them and go to those special locations.  For instance:

```
Public Music
My Documents
Recycle Bin
```

My question: is there a way for my application to add its own recognizable string there?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way is to implement a [Namespace Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144095.aspx).